# How to Communicating with an API (curl -X) in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

i have stored wishlist items in cookie ,
but in incognito tab , there is no cookie so data can't be fetched .

i've came up with something with this extension , that adds 3 endpoints
https://github.com/mediamanDE/magento-module-wishlist-api

To Get the wishlist for the user.

Example:

```
$ curl -X GET http://magento.example.com/rest/V1/wishlist --header "Authorization: Bearer pbhercbtk6dd3eatf1pyx8jj45avjluu"
```

How can i initiate or call this request in Vue ?

Comment: with `fetch()`? `axios`?

Comment: I am thinking the same , its rest api actually  which i want to call for

Comment: is the response JSON?

Comment: @Ifaruki See https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mediamanDE/magento-module-wishlist-api/master/demo.gif

Comment: Yes , json response

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```
 fetch("http://magento.example.com/rest/V1/wishlist", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer pbhercbtk6dd3eatf1pyx8jj45avjluu"
    }
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
```